# Getting DBA_USERS information

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-administration, oracle12c

I am trying to retreive a USER id, from DBA_USERS like we can do in DBA_ROLES.

I've tryied to retreive ROWID column from DBA_ROLES, but i get this warning:

"**ORA-01445: cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a join view without a key-preserved table**"

From what i can understand, DBA_USERS is a Oracle generated view and it is not possible to retrieve this ROWID. Am i right?

If this is correct, how can i know from which tables this view is generated? Or how can i know the ROWID of a USER?

Kind regards!

Sam

Comment: Your looking for a field that doesn't exists. Here is a list of fields available in DBA_USERS http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21901_01/doc/timesten.1122/e21644/systemtables.htm#TTSYS369

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am trying to retrieve a USER id, from DBA_USERS

You are looking for [`DBA_USERS.USER_ID`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21901_01/doc/timesten.1122/e21644/systemtables.htm#TTSYS369) :

```
SQL> SELECT USER_ID FROM DBA_USERS WHERE USERNAME = 'SYLVAIN'; 

   USER_ID
----------
    48
```

---

> I've tryied to retreive `ROWID` column

[`ROWID`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm) have nothing to do here. Those are kind of "pointers" to the row physical storage. Under some specific conditions they are subject to change. Since *views* don't have physical storage, `ROWID` is meaningless for them -- hence the error *"ORA-01445"* :

> <sup>from `oraerr`:</sup>
>   *ORA-01445: cannot select ROWID from a join*
>   view without a key-preserved table
>
> Cause: A SELECT statement attempted to select ROWIDs from a view
>   derived from a join operation. Because the rows selected in the view
>   do not correspond to underlying physical records, no ROWIDs can be
>   returned.
>
> Action: Remove ROWID from the view selection clause, then re-execute
>   the statement.

Answer (score 0):

What Sylvain is talking about is the `rownum` not the `rowid`. The rownum is a sequential number, whereas the rowid denotes the physical location of a row.

See here:

```
0:opal@spmdtz> select rowid, rownum, xxx.* from xxx;

Rowid             |rownum|x   |y   |
------------------------------------
AAAS/3AAGAAAbmYAAA|     1|foo1|foo2|
AAAS/3AAGAAAbmYAAB|     2|bar1|bar2|
```

The rowid can be useful when you want to update a row. You can say `where rowid= ...` or in other cases where you want to refer to a row you already "have". I believe it is the fastest way to access a row.

But I don't understand why you would need the rowid in your query.

Comment: Thanks for pointing my stupid mistake. I've edited my answer to correct that.

Answer (score 0):

DBA_USERS is a view, a view which consists of a query on a few tables.

*ORA-01445* means that Oracle cannot retrieve the ROWID you request due to the fact that you need to query the relevant table **directly** (or change the view SQL and query the ROWID also) to get the relevant ROWID (needless to say that if your view is created by joining a couple of tables — how can Oracle determine which ROWID you want?) .

The "main" table DBA_USERS gets data from is **sys.USER$** table.

To get the ROWID, first look at the SQL behind DBA_USERS (it's very simple on most IDEs) to understand which data you want to query except the ROWIDs.

Then you can just query:

```
select ROWID, USER# user_id, NAME username
from sys.USER$;
```

(or any other column you need).

Good luck!